# Настройка репликации в Redis

Tags: redis

При настройке файловера в redis возник вопрос.
При выключении Master-ноды файловер назначает мастером Slave-ноду. Все ок!
Но когда подымаю master-ноду она кушает старый конфиг и думает, что она мастер.
Та же история со Slave, при перезапуске она остановится опять Slave.
Как шарить конфиги между нодами?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам подойдёт встроенное решение для обеспечения высокой доступности: https://redis.io/topics/sentinel. Там автоматически обеспечивается возвращение одной из нод после восстановления её работоспособности.